# angular2 inject Router in component constructor error if no elvis operator

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angular

When my app starts, I want the route /home to be displayed by default.
The "useAsDefault: true" property to the route definition is not implemented yet on the Angular 2 version I use.

To solve the problem I thought doing this in app.component.ts (which is what you find in many examples on the net):

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private _router: Router) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this._router.navigate(['/home']);
  }
}
```

But I get:

"Error:(29, 12) TS2346: Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target."

If I add the Elvis operator, it works, I don't get any error:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private _router?: Router) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this._router.navigate(['/home']);
  }
}
```

Could someone help me understand why? 
My app.component.ts file:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {Router, Routes, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES } from '@angular/router';
import {NavbarComponent} from "./navbar.component";
import {UsersComponent} from "./users.components";
import {PostsComponent} from "./posts.component";
import {HomeComponent} from "./home.component";

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    templateUrl: 'app/app.component.html',
    directives: [NavbarComponent, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
})

@Routes([
  {path: '/home', component: HomeComponent},
  {path: '/users', component: UsersComponent},
  {path: '/posts', component: PostsComponent}
])

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private _router?: Router) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this._router.navigate(['/home']);
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you provide `ROUTER_PROVIDERS` anywhere, for example in `bootstrap(AppComponent, [ROUTER_PROVIDERS])`?

Comment: Yes I provide it in my main.ts with bootstrap(AppComponent, [ROUTER_PROVIDERS]);

Answer (score 2):

> If I add the Elvis operator, it works, I don't get any error

Minor: This is not called the elvis operator. Its just syntax to denote optional parameters (reference https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#3922-parameter-list)

> Could someone help me understand why

the error `Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target` points you to the fact that something is calling the constructor *without providing all the parameters*. That code is not shown in your question but you now know *why* (when you mark the parameter as optional you silence that error for obvious reasons)

Comment: Thanks! I understand your point. But the weird thing is that I still get the _router var populated. When ngOnInit is fired, the code inside it works.

Here is an example with the Router injected into the contructor:
https://angular.io/resources/live-examples/router/ts/plnkr.html